# How is $f(x,y)$ defined on the $xy$-plane?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just starting to learn differential equations, and a book I am going through claims that for a first order differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$$

$f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables "defined on a region in the $xy$-plane". However, from my point of view it seems obvious that $f(x,y)$ requires a third dimension to be drawn, as it is a function of two variables. So shouldn't it be defined with $x$,$y$, and $z$ like $z=f(x,y)$?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to see the *graph* of $f$, quite so. Still, the *values* of $f$ are just real numbers as you say.

Comment: $y=f (x) $ is a plane curve while $z=f (x,y) $ is the equation of a surface .

Comment: @MPW So "defined on a region in the xy-plane" means that the inputs to the function originate from a region defined on the plane.

Comment: @Vasting : Yes indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what they mean by "defined on a region in the $xy$-plane" is that the domain of the function (i.e. where the variables $x$ and $y$ come from) is a region in the $xy$-plane. The image of the variables does require a third dimension.